# System file partition for Windows / Linux / Mac

Tags: linux, windows, mac

I have a 1 Tb HDD that I need to use it on Windows , Red Hat Linux 5 and MAC OS X.

Is there any specific file system that I can format it with so it can be accessible from the 3 mentioned OS.

Comment: NTFS support is stable on all three. NTFS requires a third-party program on OS X.  Its supports out of the box on most distros of Linux.

Comment: In general I'd say use NTFS, but RHEL 5 is 2007 era software, back when ntfs3g wasn't as good as it is now (I have to assume you mean RHEL, since Fedora 5 is much older, and 'Red Hat Linux 5' is a mid-ninties distro). OSx shouldn't have an issue. FAT is the most compatible, but won't easily scale to the volume of data you are talking about

Comment: @FrankThomas - Even in 2007 NTFS support was stable across most distro of Linux if my memory serves me.  The driver itself hasn't been updated in awhile.

Comment: in 2007 at least with ubuntu Feisty, NTFS3G was read only. it wasn;t until 2008 or '09 (Hardy I think) that it became RW by default, after reliability/safety improvements were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NTFS. In the best case scenario, everyone will be able to read and write to it automatically. If you really *are* using Red Hat Linux 5 (which is unlikely given as it is very very old) you might have trouble there but you might be able to get it to work with an old enough version of `ntfs-3g`.

Of course, if you really are using Red Hat Linux 5, you should upgrade FAST. There really is no point in using such an old OS.

In any case, even if for some reason NTFS won't work on your Linux, you still can't do any better than it. It is by far the most portable file system around and the one most likely to be easily accessed by any OS. Especially since you also need to use it with windows.